# Angular Material Dialog alignment issues

Tags: angular, angular-material, dialog

I have style issue in material dialog.
Scenario: Recently I added one button in material dialog(say dialog1).If I am trying to navigate to some other page,after opening  dialog1 and navigate to some other page,and opening some other dialog( say dialog2) and come back to first page,and open dialog1 ,all contents will be centrally aligned.After this if I am trying to open any dialog,all the contents centrally aligned. I tried reverting code,and clear cache.Still issue persist. Any idea on this.

Comment: Do you have an un-encapsulated css from the components in your second page? Could be causing the alignment to change.

Comment: Each component have its own css,for new button added style with ng deep.How to confirm css is un- encapsulated

Comment: I can see this issue from last week,Is it because of any angular automatic  update

Comment: ng-deep could be leaking into global if you are not wrapping it in some way. If you post your CSS I'd be happy to take a further look